# Replacing text in NSTextFieldCell inside NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Whenever a user would type a number, my app would automatically prepend a currency sign before that number. For example, when the user types "1" in a text field, the text inside it becomes "$1.00". All is good when I use an NSNumberFormatter, an NSTextField, and its delegate method `control:didFailToFormatString:errorDescription:`.

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control didFailToFormatString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString *)error
{    

    if ([[control formatter] isKindOfClass:[NSNumberFormatter class]])
    {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [control formatter];

        if ([formatter numberStyle] == NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle && !
            [string hasPrefix:[formatter currencySymbol]])
        {

            NSDecimalNumber *new = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string];
            if (new == [NSDecimalNumber notANumber]) {
                new = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
            }
            [control setObjectValue:new];
        }
    }

    return YES;}
```

Now I would like to have this functionality when a user types a number in a cell inside an NSTableView. I tried using `control:didFailToFormatString:errorDescription:` but the cell would erase the text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to let everybody know that I have solved the problem by asking for the NSTableView's currentEditor, and replacing the text from there.

Additionally, `[control formatter]` will return nil if the receiver is an NSTableView.

Comment: I tried the following : `NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[self.tableView currentEditor] formatter];` And its showing error : `No visible @interface for NSText declares the selector formatter.` Because `[tableview currentEditor]` returns `NSText`. Where did you actually change?